# Find non-ASCII text in a file

Tags: search, unicode, grep, cpu-word, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to find the Greek word `μάθηση` in a file, which in Unicode characters is `\u03bc\u03ac\u03b8\u03b7\u03c3\u03b7` using `grep`.  I tried this command

```
grep -r $"\u03bc\u03ac\u03b8\u03b7\u03c3\u03b7" filename.txt
```

but it failed. Any help?

Comment: Why not `grep 'μάθηση'`?

Comment: It does not work at all.

Comment: @Nick which encoding is being used in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works on my Mac with `zsh`:

```bash
fgrep "$(echo '\u03bc\u03ac\u03b8\u03b7\u03c3\u03b7')" filename.txt
```

and the following works on my Mac with `bash` 3.2.57 (for those who don't know: Apple switched to zsh instead of switching to bash version 4, because of licensing concerns)

```bash
fgrep "$(echo -e '\xce\xbc\xce\xac\xce\xb8\xce\xb7\xcf\x83\xce\xb7')" filename.txt
```

The builtin version of `echo` in bash (which you can read about with `man bash`, *not* with `man echo`) needs the `-e` option to expand certain escape sequences (`\x` in this case), but `\u` (Unicode) is not among these. I don't know whether this is different in newer versions of bash.

To find the UTF-8 hex representation of the search string I did an `od -tx1` of a text file where I had written `μάθηση`. Of course, here I'm supposing your file is UTF-8-encoded.

---

**The following should always work, though:**<sup>(*)</sup>

Write `μάθηση` in a 1-line file, say it's called `grepfile.txt`, then

```bash
fgrep -f grepfile.txt filename.txt
```

(tested on Mac with `bash` and `zsh`)

(*): This solution should work as long as the encoding of both files is the same (you can check the encoding with the `file` command, keeping in mind that 7-bit ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, but also of all ISO-8859-* encodings).

Comment: The 1st one does not work for me. The other two commands are ok, though I noticed they might not be working  for .doc .docx files

Comment: that's normal, you can't expect to find any text in .doc and .docx files. You _may_ find a single word in a .pdf file, but that's all for non strictly text formats. Anyway, I added quotes around the `$()` parts, because otherwise you wouldn't be able search for anything containing a space.